# azure devops pipeline failure when using private github submodule in a private github repo

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two private github repo's and one repo is used as a submodule in the other.
The .git modules looks like this

```
[submodule "submodule"]
    path = submodule
    url = ../submodule
```

I have an two factor SSO , so I use a PAT to access these repos.

I build these in AzureDevOps and I have a service connection with my PAT.b below is my pipeline yaml.

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      type: GitHub
      name: myorg/main
      connection: github.com_connectionid
      pr:
        branches:
          include:
          - main
      trigger:
        batch: true
        branches:
          include:
          - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
    persistCredentials: true
```

With this the submodule checkout fails. with this error

```
2021-05-02T17:01:06.3578223Z HEAD is now at 9560ded fix persist credentials
2021-05-02T17:01:06.3581105Z ##[command]git submodule sync
2021-05-02T17:01:06.3590245Z ##[command]git -c http.https://github.com.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" submodule update --init --force
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7063231Z Submodule 'submodule' (https://github.com/myorg/submodule) registered for path 'submodule'
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7065477Z Cloning into '/home/vsts/work/1/s/submodule'...
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7066269Z remote: Repository not found.
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7067185Z fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myorg/submodule/' not found
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7068915Z fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/myorg/submodule' into submodule path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/submodule' failed
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7070000Z Failed to clone 'submodule'. Retry scheduled
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7070925Z Cloning into '/home/vsts/work/1/s/submodule'...
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7071592Z remote: Repository not found.
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7072746Z fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myorg/submodule/' not found
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7073981Z fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/myorg/submodule' into submodule path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/submodule' failed
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7075750Z Failed to clone 'submodule' a second time, aborting
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7132523Z ##[error]Git submodule update failed with exit code: 1
2021-05-02T17:01:06.7332338Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout myorg/main@main to s
```

changing persistCredentials has no effect.

Adding full path in the URL has no effect.
The main repo is checked out successfully with the same service connection.
Names of 'main' and 'submodule' have been changed from the original.

Answer (score 1):

I have a work around for now,  I disable submodule checkout and do It manually. this was inspired by a similar issue https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/116#issuecomment-573880976.

```
variables:
  - group: GIT_PAT    

- script: |
          env
          ls -la
          git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp url | while read url; do
          git config --file=.gitmodules $(echo "$url" | sed -E "s/git@github.com:|https:\/\/github.com\//https:\/\/$(CI_PAT):$(CI_PAT)@github.com\//")
          done
          git submodule sync
          git submodule update --init --recursive
        displayName: checkout submodule
```

CI_PAT is stored as a secret in the variable group GIT_PAT.

This works